# Thinktecture Identity Server vs MembershipReboot Multi Tenancy

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, membershipreboot

I tried to install two identity servers and both of them use the same MembershipReboot database with Multi Tenancy setting in identity server web.config. (defaultTenant="A" multiTenant="false") and (defaultTenant="B" multiTenant="false")

then I can saw the [UserAccounts] of MembershipReboot database what I accounts created on these two identity servers .

But When I try to login portal client from pass through these two identity servers. portal client passed to the Tenant A can login successful. but the other portal client passed through the Tenant B not.

I don't know how to fix it, may someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer v2 does not support multi-tenancy.